# "Fake hacker code" in html with css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found some code I wanted to test out. What am I missing here?
I don't have a lot of experience using JS and I am not sure if I'm missing something. I would be really happy if anyone is able to help!
Here is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spaced.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://test.noa16.png"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<p class="text" data-text="test text 010101101010101 lolol whatever"</p>
<script>
   var printText = $('.text').data('text');

var contentArray = printText.split('/n');
$.each(contentArray, function(index, newLine) {
  $('.text').append('<span style="display:block;" id="'+index+'"></span>');

  var lineID = index;
  var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
      $.each(self, function(index, chunk){
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('#'+lineID).append("<span>"+chunk+"</span>");
            $('body, html').scrollTop($(document).height());
          }, index*5);
      });

    }, index*100);
}); 
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
span {
  min-width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: #FFF;
}

body {
  background: #111;
  position: relative;
}

body, html {
   height: 100%;
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working for me?

Comment: Your `p` tag isn't properly formatted. Other than that: you haven't told us what you want this code to do, or what it's currently doing that you don't want it to?

Comment: Hey! I want it to work like shown here: https://codepen.io/hparton/pen/idDGK?editors=1011

Comment: OK, well the broken `p` tag really seems to be all there is to it. You haven't closed it. `"</p>` should be `"></p>`.

Comment: I just messed up the p tag here, as you can see in the link there's alot of random text that I removed. But on the site live right now, the p tag is closed. But when I load the page, it only shows a black screen. No text shows up!

Comment: Are you including the jQuery lib? Doesn't look like it in your code above. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yay! That did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Close your `<p>` tag
2. The script uses jQuery,notice the `$` sign, download it or use a CDN and place it above your script
3. Make sure that the page is fully loaded before executing the code

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       // your script here
   });
   ```